# Jquery EasyUI Escaping HTML strings

Tags: javascript, jquery-easyui

I use easyui datagrid to show my data.

There are multiple columns need to escape. For example, if the column is with `field: "username"` and the `username` is `<script>alert('hi!');</script>`, it is vulnerable to XSS attacks.

What i need is not the escape function since i have a large number of columns. I do not want to escape by manual for each column in datagrid. I want to know if esayui has some simple global configure or uniform-function to solve this problem.

I cannot find any configures or settings about escape uniformly in easyui doc. someone can help me? Thanks.